# error cannot find module 'umask'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, umask

I just installed **nodejs x64** on my Windows 10 computer. I keep all default config, 
I open cmd and type:
`npm -v`

Then i got following error:

```
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'umask'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\W10-PRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module\npm\lib\utils\umask.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Every command start with "npm" create this error and npm cannot uninstall, update itself)
Please help me fix this error?

Comment: How did you install npm? What happens when you attempt to uninstall it?

Comment: Same error here... Also on Windows 10...

Answer (score 2):

update your npm

```
$ npm install npm -g
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to update/install NPM

```
$ npm update -g npm
```

Comment: npm cannot update or uninstall itself, it throw the same error

Comment: How did you install nodejs? I would recommend using nvm or something like that... maybe you could `npm install -g umask` so that it would find it anyway, but it might not be the only one missing.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this error by create a new windows user account, log in this account and install nodejs. Other account still not work, Perhap the old account (named: "W10-PRO") have special character (i think "-" character)  that didn't processed property

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer!

Uninstall nodejs.

Delete all references to npm and nodejs (Program Files, Program Files(x86).
Then also delete those in AppData/Roaming (npm and npm-cache to be sure).

Reinstall nodejs.

It works!