# Node.Js - NPM - Error: Cannot find module 'umask' in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed **Node.JS 64x version 8.10.0 in windows 10**. And everytime I use **npm** command in "**cmd**" always got this error. I tried this solution but still has the same error, topic: "[error cannot find module 'umask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469580/error-cannot-find-module-umask?newreg=472f79fda7854aba8afbcb45a7a0b97a)". Does anyone has a clue? Thank you very much.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm --version
>
> module.js:549
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'umask'
>
> ```
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
> at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\3702e81b\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\umask.js:1:75)
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> ```

Comment: Are you using NVM?

Comment: no, I am not using NVM.

Comment: Fixed it, I deleted "node_modules" folder in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\3702e81b\taco-toolset-6.3.1" folder.